# Other flags are also inserting into flag_friend table

Tags: 7, flags

I have a user flag "shortlist". And I also installed [Flag Friend](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_friend) module.
This module creates a default flag named as "*friend*".

I am creating these two flag links in "*user-profile.tpl.php*".`

```
flag_create_link('shortlist', $uid);
flag_create_link('friend', $uid);
```

If I am flagging **shortlist** tab the flag data inserting into `flag_friend` table. How would this happen? I need to insert flag data into the `flag_friend` table if the flag type is only "*friend*".